# Save instances from Mongodb collection as string variables in an Atlas Trigger Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to set up a MongoDB Atlas trigger function that searches a mongoDB database to collect string variables, then uses those as the to log into a separate API. When I run this function:

```js
exports = function() {      
  const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
  const EventData = mongodb.db("SIoT").collection("EventData");
    
  var data = EventData.find({"_id":new BSON.ObjectId("XXXXXXXX")})
      
  return data  
};
```

It returns:

```
EJSON.parse('[{"_id":{"$oid":"XXXXXXXXX"},"CodeRequestAuthorization":"XXXXXXXXXXX","DataRequestAuthorization":"XXXXXXXXXX"}]')
```

But I am trying to save the CodeRequestAuthorization value as a variable in the function.

Feels like an incredibly simple problem but I have been stuck for about 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem myself:

```
exports = async function(){
  
  const EventData = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("SIoT").collection("EventData");
  const request = await EventData.findOne({"_id":new BSON.ObjectId("XXXXXXXXXXX")});

  var data = request.XXXXXXX;
```